# Facebook login via application in Unity3d

Tags: c#, facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have several builds of the Unity3d game (Dev, Stage), and i have several appropriate Facebook test apps (each of them has different Fb_id).

When i'm doing Facebook login in the Dev build, my game is closed and Facebook application is opened, so i can log in with 1 click, so i don't need to enter my creds (if i'm already logged in to a Facebook app).

When i'm doing Facebook login in the Stage build, a Facebook canvas is opened on top of my game, so every time i need to input my creds to login.

However, it seems the settings are the same for both builds. How can i set Stage build to use Facebook app instead of canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/dialogs/v2.2), there should be a 'FacebookDisplayName' in plist. That was not a real solution, but it pushed me forward.

The thing is that Fb_id in project settings (stored in FacebookSettings.asset) should equals to the one in plist (FacebookAppId). Otherwise, canvas would be opened for login instead of Facebook app.